# spring rest response adding $type property in the response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring mvc 3.2.3.RELEASE
This is my EndPoint

```
@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, value = "getEmployees")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getEmployeeInfo(@RequestBody EmployeeReqDTO employeeReqDTO)
        
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();

        emp1.setAge("23");
        emp1.setName("Test");

        Employee emp2 = new Employee();

        emp2.setAge("222");
        emp2.setName("Iran");

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

        empList.add(emp1);
        empList.add(emp2);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(empList, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

I get the following response

```
[
    {
        "$type": "Employee",
        "Name": "Test",
        "Age": "23"
    },
    {
        "$type": "Employee",
        "Name": "Iran",
        "Age": "222"
    }
]
```

I dont need the **"$type"** property in the response , how to remove it ??

Comment: Replace with ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> in both places.

Comment: @Alien when the response type is of ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> , it has still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Replace with `ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>` in both places.

It's happening because spring doesn't know what you want to return.

Comment: I am trying to send the following response 

Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();

and used the same way as 
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> , but the same issue exists for this response type